# jQuery .load problem

Tags: jquery, load

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function show() {
        var text=$("#text").val();
        $("#output").load("index.htm");
    }

    function send() {
        var text=$("#text").val();

        $.post("new.php",{'txt':text});
        $("#text").val(" ");
    }

</script>

</head>
<body onload="javascript:window.setInterval('show()', 1000)">

<input type="text" id="text">
<div id="output">CHange</div>
<input type="button" value="Send" onclick="send()">

</body>
```

Now the problem i'm facing is that  `$("#output").load("index.htm");` doesn't seem to do anything :/
Please Help!

Comment: What error are you seeing in the error console? Did you debug the code and confirmed it reaches `show()`?

Comment: Well this code works, allright. Anant do you actually have this file "index.htm" in your working directory?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use clean unobtrusive code. `body.onload` is also a pretty questionable place to execute some code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    show();
});
```

should do it. I'm not sure why you would call that within an ´interval` ?

Comment: it seems to be working now. I guess a browser specific problem :O .Works just fine on FireFox

Comment: @Anant: Possible, that's why I mentioned the bad place at `body.onload`. jQuerys `.ready()` normalizes through all browser a reliable method.